# How to "reference/import" an svg from public folder inside an scss file in src folder?

Tags: css, reactjs, svg, sass, background-image

I want to set the background of an element to an svg; therefore, I need to know how to "reference/import" an svg from the public folder into the scss file in the src folder?

My react application's structure:

```
-- node_modules
-- public
 | -- times.svg
-- src
 | -- index.scss      <-- How do I reference 'times.svg' from here?
```

I have tried:

```
background: url("public/times.svg");
```

But it results in:

> Error: Can't resolve 'public/times-solid.svg' in 'C:\Users...\project\src'

I have also tried:

```
background: url("../../public/times.svg");
```

> Module not found: You attempted to import ../../public/times.svg which falls outside of the project src/ directory. Relative imports outside of src/ are not supported.

Answer (score 0):

you can import local images from the public folder as below:

```
background-image: url('/sample.svg');
```

[working example in sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/optimistic-bardeen-9jw7f?file=/src/styles.scss)